# How should I segregate a network into relevant zones with different access requirements?

Tags: security, networking, vpn, cisco

Currently, we have a "HQ" network and a "Branch" network that are completely independent and physically separated in different locations.

[This is the current network diagram.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/b92Jw.png)

We've been tasked to look at improving security on a fictional network for practice, whilst also adding some DMZs for:

- A static website that is accessible by the public.
- A web server that is accessible by clients with a VPN.

The Branch and HQ networks should also be linked by a VPN to allow the users in the LAN of the Branch to access resources in the HQ LAN.

My initial ideas are:

- Change both HQ and Branch Routers to be Cisco ASA devices and have them as VPN endpoints, removing the now-unnecessary ASA between the HQ Router and Internal Network.
- Add the two required DMZs directly from interfaces from the ASA, setting trust zones as required.

My questions are:

1. Is it a bad idea to replace the Routers with Firewalls? If so, how could I still setup a VPN tunnel between the Branch and HQ easily?
2. Do I need any other Firewalls (e.g. between the Internal Network and the external Firewall)? If so, why?
3. How could I configure the network so that one of the DMZs is accessibly only by those on the External Network with a VPN?

Answer (score 0):

Depends on how tight you need to secure your network.
If there is no demand to “hide” router behind firewall the usual way is to place one interface of ASA outside at the same ISP network where router is placed and order IP for it. Other ASA interfaces you could connect to router internal interface (to firewall company traffic) and to DMZ segments.
At this case you could gather requests to your Web server and transfer it to DMZ. And at the same time you could firewall internal company traffic as well.
If you don’t have enough physical interfaces on ASA you could just use switch and do the same with use of switch vlans and ASA sub interfaces (don’t forget to configure switch interfaces in secure way).